# SQL SUM and COUNT in acces

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm using Microsoft Access as backend. This is the ERD I made:

[image]

These are the tables I have:

**VERTONING:**

[image]

**FILM:**

[image]

This is the SQL I made:

```
SELECT titel
    ,COUNT(vertoning) AS [aantal vertoningen]
    ,SUM(aantaldagen) AS [aantal dagen]
FROM film,vertoning
WHERE vertoning = "bioscoop"
GROUP BY titel;
```

However, if I run the query, I get this:

[image: http://puu.sh/ebWAh/8f9a1346b6.png]

While I should get this:

[image]

It seems like it counts up from everything instead of showing how much of "bioscoop" there is for each "filmcode"

If something is not clear I'll try to explain it.

(I could only post 2 links so sorry for the spaces in the first 3 links)

Comment: Don't you need a join condition? (Add AND film.filmcode = vertoning.filmcode to your WHERE clause.)

Comment: Yes, I needed to use a join condition for this.
I used your line my clause and the results were like what I wanted to have!
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT Film.Titel, 
       COUNT(Vertoning.vertoning) AS [aantal vertoningen], 
       SUM(Vertoning.aantaldagen) AS [aantal dagen]
FROM Film INNER JOIN Vertoning ON Film.FilmCode = Vertoning.Filmcode
WHERE Vertoning.vertoning = "bioscoop"
GROUP BY Film.titel;
```

Let me know if it works or not

Comment: This seems to work too just like the join jarlh suggested me to do. Thank you!